# What kind of secrecy can be obtained by hiding an organization's EIN (tax number?)

Tags: united-states, tax-law, non-profit, north-carolina

I am a treasurer for an organization under a local high school in North Carolina, in the United States. The organization I am treasurer for is not registered with the IRS, but the school system is.

We are seeking to do a nonprofit crowdfunding campaign in [IndieGoGo,](http://indiegogo.com) and they require our organization's EIN number. We have received that number from our treasurer, and are attempting to use it, but it does not show up in IndieGoGo, nor does it show up as an exempt organization on the IRS's [Exempt Organization Select Check.](https://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Exempt-Organizations-Select-Check) Additionally, my supervisor informs me that the schoolsystem's EIN number is kept under tight secrecy, for reasons I cannot fathom.

Are there any benefits for keeping this number secret? **More specifically, is there some sort of tax exempt organization status that does not have the records publically available?**